# Logger doesn't write to file Log4J

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j

I don't understand why my Log4J is not logging to file. Ive been looking many similar posts but none helped me. I configured all correctly, but it doesn't log to the file.

Let me show you, this is the config log4J.properties:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, stdout

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=log.out
log4j.appender.file.ImmediateFlush=true
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1024MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.Append=true
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

And this is how I use the Logger:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

...

private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GameBoardService.class);


...

logger.info("log this text into file....");
```

Comment: Did you checked if your log4j.properties file get correctly picked up?

Comment: Did you try giving full path of the file like C:/log.out?

Comment: Did you add the `log4j-slf4j-impl.jar` file to the classpath? Oh, sorry, you're using the *old* Log4j 1.2. Did you add the `slf4j-log4j12.jar` file to the classpath?

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify your base package for the logging

```
log4j.logger.[your own class base package ]=INFO
```

e.g.

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework=WARN
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=WARN
```

Be specific with the log path to enable you to easily locate the path, e.g. below.

```
log4j.appender.file.File=/var/logs/log.out
```

Furthermore, /var/logs/log.out is created in `Windows` as C:\var\logs\log.out and in `Linux` as /var/logs/log.out and there is no need to switch path slashes according to OS. Just a reminder, ensure you have permission to the specified path.